# ipset rules being ignored when blocking Amazon Web Services

Tags: iptables, amazon-web-services, firewall

I'm downloading the list of CIDRs for Amazon Web Services here:

https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json

And then putting them on a ipset with the line:

```
sudo ipset -q -A tor $ip
```

And blocking with iptables with the line:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set tor src -j DROP
```

In total there are about 65,000 IPs in the ipset *tor*. It also has tor IPs blocked and a few others and this is working fine for those, but for some reason it seems unable to block any Amazon IPs.

Any ideas?

Full list of rules:

```
sudo ipset -N whitelist nethash
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT                                  
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set whitelist src -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -N BLOCK24
sudo iptables -A BLOCK24 -m recent --name blocked --set
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 300 --hitcount 200 -j BLOCK24
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m recent --name blocked --rcheck --seconds 86400 -j BLOCK24
sudo iptables -A BLOCK24 -j LOG --log-prefix='[NETFILTER] ' --log-level 7
sudo iptables -A BLOCK24 -j REJECT
```

Then first I run these to destory and re-create the block list:

```
sudo iptables -D INPUT -m set --match-set tor src -j DROP
sudo ipset destroy tor
sudo ipset -N tor iphash
```

Add cira 65K IPs with:

```
sudo ipset -q -A tor $ip
```

Add ipset to iptables:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set tor src -j DROP
```

Again, everything is blocked except Amazon.

Comment: Often it is impossible to diagnose iptables issues properly without seeing the complete firewall config. In general though a frequent issue is that **`-A`**  option adds that new rule, **after all existing rules** and that rules are processed in order. One of the preceding rules may be preventing your new rule from matching. The counters in `iptables -L -v -n --line-numbers` may help diagnose if that's the issue.

Comment: I suspect you need to be using set type "hash:net" rather than "hash:ip" as the entries in the JSON file are net/mask notation.

Comment: @parkamark - That is the correct answer. If you post it as the answer I will accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The set type needs to be <kbd>hash:net</kbd> rather than <kbd>hash:ip</kbd> as the entries in the JSON file are net/mask notation.